# Wrong kernel module getting loaded for fiber interfaces

Tags: rhel, kernel-modules, network-interface

I have an HP Gen 9 server running RHEL 7.4, with 3 network interface kernel modules, ixgbe, bnx2x, and tg3.  Whenever the system gets rebooted, bnx2x and ixgbe seem to get randomly assigned to interfaces.  I have specified device mac addresses in the ifcfg files, but they still don't get assigned correctly after a reboot.  I have to manually remove ixgbe and bnx2x, and reload them in a certain order, for the modules to be properly assigned.

I need:

- eth7 to use ixgbe
- eth6 to use ixgbe
- eth2-5 to use bnx2x
- eth0-1 to use tg3 (This module seems to always load correctly)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is interface naming setup on RHEL 7.4? Via `udec` rules? Did you look at the rules in `/etc`, and is there a file for persistent network interface names? If yes, can you edit it with your preferences?

Comment: We have set our interface names to be persistent, using the the eth0-7 naming scheme.  I can't make any changes to this naming scheme, unfortunately.

Comment: *How* have you "set your interface names to be persistent"? Did this create a rule file for `udev`?

Comment: we pass biosdevname=0 to kernel from the kickstart file itself
and RHEL keeps that and puts it in grub.conf.  We do not use udev rules.

Comment: The MAC addresses in the ifcfg won't affect assignment of device names. Without udev rules, names get assigned in the order they are initialized, which can be random, as initialization is started in parallel. You do need udev rules to make predictable/persistent assignments.